# Identities proved using Stein's Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

Let ${X}$ be a real random variable with the probability density function ${x \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}}$ of the standard normal distribution. Then we have the Stein identity

$\displaystyle {\bf E} X F(X) = {\bf E} F'(X)$

whenever ${F: {\bf R} \rightarrow {\bf R}}$ is a continuously differentiable function with ${F}$ and ${F'}$ both of polynomial growth. Use this identity recursively to establish the identities.

$\displaystyle {\bf E} X^k = 0$

when ${k}$ is an odd natural number and

$\displaystyle {\bf E} X^k = (k-1) (k-3) \dots 1 = \frac{k!}{2^{k/2} (k/2)!}$

when ${k}$ is an even natural number.

**Question:** For any natural number $k > 0$, it seems that the result obtained by letting $F: \mathbf{R} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ be defined by $F(x) = \frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}$ and regarded $\mathbf{E}X^k$ as $\mathbf{E}F'(X)$, is different from the result obtained by letting $F: \mathbf{R} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ be defined by $F(x) := x^{k-1}$ and regarded $\mathbf{E}X^k$ as $\mathbf{E}XF(X)$, which of course makes no sense. What's the issue here?

Comment: You are saying you did the problem in two ways, and got two different answers. You must have made some kind of mistake in one of the ways. Can you show your work, please, so we can better diagnose what went wrong?

Comment: @MikeEarnest: Now that I look back it seems that I've spotted the issue. The first approach would have produced $\mathbf{E} X^k = \frac{1}{k+1} \mathbf{E}X^{k+2}$, a term which can not be easily controlled (And most importantly, not recursive). So one should really go with the second approach instead.